# Eye blink detection with OpenCV and Python error

Tags: python, opencv

This code has been verified through an internet search.
Installation and execution of all required modules will result in errors.
this is pythoh code

```
from scipy.spatial import distance as dist
from imutils.video import FileVideoStream
from imutils.video import VideoStream
from imutils import face_utils
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import time
import dlib
import cv2

def eye_aspect_ratio(eye):

    A = dist.euclidean(eye[1], eye[5])
    B = dist.euclidean(eye[2], eye[4])
    C = dist.euclidean(eye[0], eye[3])

    ear = (A + B) / (2.0 * C)

    return ear

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-p", "--shape-predictor", required=True,
    help="path to facial landmark predictor")
ap.add_argument("-v", "--video", type=str, default="",
    help="path to input video file")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

EYE_AR_THRESH = 0.3
EYE_AR_CONSEC_FRAMES = 3


COUNTER = 0
TOTAL = 0

print("[INFO] loading facial landmark predictor...")
detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
predictor = dlib.shape_predictor(args["shape_predictor"])


(lStart, lEnd) = face_utils.FACIAL_LANDMARKS_IDXS["left_eye"]
(rStart, rEnd) = face_utils.FACIAL_LANDMARKS_IDXS["right_eye"]


print("[INFO] starting video stream thread...")
vs = FileVideoStream(args["video"]).start()
fileStream = True

time.sleep(1.0)


while True:

    if fileStream and not vs.more():
        break


    frame = vs.read()
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=450)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


    rects = detector(gray, 0)


    for rect in rects:

        shape = predictor(gray, rect)
        shape = face_utils.shape_to_np(shape)


        leftEye = shape[lStart:lEnd]
        rightEye = shape[rStart:rEnd]
        leftEAR = eye_aspect_ratio(leftEye)
        rightEAR = eye_aspect_ratio(rightEye)


        ear = (leftEAR + rightEAR) / 2.0


        leftEyeHull = cv2.convexHull(leftEye)
        rightEyeHull = cv2.convexHull(rightEye)
        cv2.drawContours(frame, [leftEyeHull], -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)
        cv2.drawContours(frame, [rightEyeHull], -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)


        if ear < EYE_AR_THRESH:
            COUNTER += 1


        else:

            if COUNTER >= EYE_AR_CONSEC_FRAMES:
                TOTAL += 1

            COUNTER = 0


        cv2.putText(frame, "Blinks: {}".format(TOTAL), (10, 30),
            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 255), 2)
        cv2.putText(frame, "EAR: {:.2f}".format(ear), (300, 30),
            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 255), 2)

    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    if key == ord("q"):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
vs.stop()
```

and error

usage: detect_blinks.py [-h] -p SHAPE_PREDICTOR [-v VIDEO]
detect_blinks.py: error: the following arguments are required: -p/--shape-predictor

Can you tell me why?

Comment: The error literally tells you why. **error: the following arguments are required: -p/--shape-predictor** So you need to provide the path to the facial landmark predictor

Comment: You got the code from somewhere, there should the predictor be provided... my guess is that it is a file which describes the facial landmark.